# Barcode pre-processing for zbar

Tags: opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi, barcode, zbar

I'm using a raspberry pi camera to read barcodes from an image, and the object needs to be relatively far from the camera in my application. The barcode before processing: [image: Before]

Zbar was unable to decode anything from this image, and I decided to try and edit the image manually to get it to decode. After drawing clear white lines between the single lines of the barcode and changing the contrast of the image, this result was decoded by ZBar: [image: After]

How can I programmatically go from the first image to the second image (I am using OpenCV with python right now)?

Comment: Looks like you need more detailed picture (better focussed?) of the barcode - more pixels - choices are a higher-resolution camera, a zoom lense, move the barcode closer to the camera, a bigger barcode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite simple considering the darkest area is black and any greyish area needs to be converted to white. Try computing the mean intensity of the image.

cv::Scalar avgPixelIntensity = cv::mean( image );

Using this value as threshold, you can do Image threshold. This will be quite fast.

You can also try Otsu Thresholding which is an adaptive thresholding technique. This will be slower than above method but will provide better results in cases when image has other artefacts such as shadows.

See here: [Image Thresholding Opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html).

Comment: The problem is the average will likely not be the correct threshold value, since the image is not half pixels black and half pixels white. Also, when you actually zoom in, the difference between the gray pixels making up the vertical line and the "white" pixels between is actually quite small, so even a slightly incorrect threshold could have drastic effects

Comment: @glaba Can you post an image where average as a threshold wont work? Secondly, did you get a chance to check OTSU. I recommended OTSU as it is used exactly for this purpose in OCR applications. If neither works, using edge detection paired with Hough Line Detector will get you all lines, but then reading the text characters will be a problem left unsolved. P.S. OTSU should work as it computes threshold parameters locally, so it will take difference between the gray line and its white background. It wont consider the very black lines if you are not using a sufficiently small window.

Comment: @glaba Typo: The last line should say: "It wont consider the very black lines if you are using a sufficiently small window.:

Comment: I decided that since time isn't a very important factor, I could try thresholding at multiple values because the average value does not usually work. Thresholding at various values generally does work though when the image isn't blurry. However, if it doesn't work consistently I will definitely look at OTSU.

Comment: @glaba: Please can you comment what was your final approach - Otsu or Thresholding at multiple levels? This will help others in future.

Comment: I used adaptive thresholding but it is still unreliable (although I suspect this is more due to the limitations of the camera, which is fixed focus)

Answer (score 1):

Try Thresholding it.

First convert it to greyscale and then by trial and error try to get the best possible value between 0-255 and mark all the pixels above the value chosen as white and all below as black.

If it doesn't work then the input image needs to have more clarity.

(Not sure if the zbar library already does this)